# Validate user entry on Worksheet_Change event

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Using Excel
I am having a devil of a time trying to get the included code to work.
I am attempting to restrict the values entered into a cell to only "A/B/C"  They can be entered in either upper or lower case.  If the value is entered in lower case then this script does successfully change the value to upper case.

The coding falls over when a value other than "A/B/C" is entered.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

- nothing is entered and passes the sanity check
- A is entered and passes the sanity check
- B is entered and passes the sanity check
- C is entered and passes the sanity check
- a is entered and fails the sanity check, is converted to A
- b is entered and fails the sanity check, is converted to B
- c is entered and fails the sanity check, is converted to C
- anything else is entered and fails the sanity check, is converted to "" (Empty)

I have remarked out the line that fails.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C9:C51")) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        With Target
            If UCase(.Text) <> .Text Then
                .Value = UCase(.Text)
            ' ElseIf .Text < "A" Or .Text > "C" Then .Value = ""
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

    <strike>Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
        If Intersect(Target, Range("C9:C51")) Is Nothing Then
        Else
            With Target
                If UCase(.Text) <> .Text Then
                    .Value = UCase(.Text)
                    If .Value = "A" Or .Value = "B" Or .Value = "C" Then
                    Else
                        .ClearContents
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End Sub</strike>

**EDIT#1:**

Based on the comment below, this should be used instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C9:C51")) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        With Target
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                    .Value = UCase(.Text)
                    If .Value = "A" Or .Value = "B" Or .Value = "C" Then
                    Else
                        .ClearContents
                    End If
                Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.     Unfortunately  .clear also clears the formatting. :-)   And, entering a number in the cell is accepted.  I would like to blank the cell for values other than A,B,C but accept a,b,c and convert them to upper case.

Comment: @YowE3K  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: @Antony  We both should thank YowE3K who did the hard part.

Comment: Hi Guys,  Found a bug.   If you block delete the range of cells, the script throws an error.     Its ok if you delete the entry on a single cell but if you select a number of cells in the range, unfortunately the script errors. @YowE3K